# Cron expression combining two ranges for days of the week

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

Can I use two ranges in a cron expression for the days of the week?

I need to run the code all the weekdays except Thursday.

What I did is

```
0 0 11 * * SUN-WED,FRI-SAT
```

Will it work as expected?

Comment: *"in the field of spring boot"* What field is that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. you can go to this https://crontab.guru/ and experiment your cron expression

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html, This site interactive section which give me below cron expression for your problem

```
0 0 11 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,FRI,SAT *
```